# Entity Framework 6 two different collections referring same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got the following scenario:

Users that can be presidents or managers of communities. When specifying a navigation property to connect the community to its president and manages, I got this:

```
public class Community
{
    ...

    [ForeignKey("President")]
    public int? PresidentId { get; set; }
    public virtual User President { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Manager")]
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
}
```

But here comes the part that I can't find a solution. I would like to have two collections on users reffering each to the communities they manage, and the ones they preside:

```
public class User
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Community> ManagedCommunities { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Community> PresidedCommunities { get; set; }
}
```

And I can't find any documentation on how to make the first one point only to the ones the user manages and the second to the ones he's presising.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can load the collections on the methods I use to retrieve the data, what I'm wondering is that entity framework got a way to define that kind of relationship.

Comment: Another possible approach is to make "CommunityRelation" table with an added property of "IsManager/IsPresident" or some enum value to indicate that. This will also give you the ability to later on add more role types easily and without changing much of the existing logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in [Code First Data Annotations (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Relationships), you can use the [`InverseProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

```
[InverseProperty("Manager")] 
public virtual ICollection<Community> ManagedCommunities { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("President")] 
public virtual ICollection<Community> PresidedCommunities { get; set; }
```

Comment: I REALLY think I shold work more into my googling skills. Thanks a lot, now I feel a bit embarrased (marking as correct when timer is due).